# Sharing pre-release NuGet packages

Tags: c#, nuget, dependency-management

Given the following set-up:

```
SolutionA
 |_ LibA -> Creates LibA.*.nupkg

SolutionB:
 |_ LibB -> Creates LibB.*.nupkg. Depends on LibA.*.nupkg
```

What is the simplest way to share development versions between the projects i.e. I update LibA creating LibA.1.0.0-beta.nupkg and then consume it in LibB?

- Several devleopers should be able to make changes to LibA simultaneously and work with their modified copies.  They should not be picking up other changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution I'm considering is as follows:

1. Add a local directory as a NuGet feed
2. Add a post build step that packages the library and adds it to the local directory feed

Then it should just be a case of taking pre-release package dependencies and updating as required.